# Ubuntu cursor is invisible after a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on a Dell Power Edge T140

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gui

While installing Ubuntu 18.04.3 the cursor was visible and working. After installation and restart, the cursor is invisible. I tried a bunch of solutions mentioned online:

`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false`

`sudo service lightdm restart`

`sudo apt-get install gdm`

I even tried reinstalling the OS.

None of these and other conventional solutions work. Anyone have an idea how to get this cursor back?

Comment: Just to be clear: invisible but basically functional? I mean: can you blindly move it, (miss)click somewhere and do something? Or you can't, as if there was no cursor at all? If the latter: is your pointing device (e.g. mouse) OK?

Comment: I can blindly move it and click somewhere. It’s weird because during the installer the cursor was visible and functional, but after installations it disappeared.

Comment: same thing here, short research gave result that in any case desktop is configured to never use a mouse cursor , in "touchscreen" mode. Just some touchscreen fanboy accidentally (I hope) up-streamed his tweaks, I guess.

Comment: Try with the Wayland session.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with lightdm on xorg (default values are to hide cursor as if a touchscreen is used).

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```